# Are there boost::bind issues with VS2010?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, boost, bind

I had the following code line which compiles just fine under g++ and Visual Studio prior to 2010.

```
std::vector<Device> device_list;

boost::function<void (Device&, boost::posix_time::time_duration&)> callback = 
  boost::bind(&std::vector<Device>::push_back, &device_list, _1);
```

Where `Device` is a class, nothing special about it.

Now I just upgraded my Visual Studio version to 2010 and compilation fails with:

```
Error   1   error C2780: 'boost::_bi::bind_t<_bi::dm_result<MT::* ,A1>::type,boost::_mfi::dm<M,T>,_bi::list_av_1<A1>::type> boost::bind(M T::* ,A1)' : expects 2 arguments - 3 provided C:\developments\libsystools\trunk\src\upnp_control_point.cpp    95
```

What is going on and how can I solve this ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is probably because `vector::push_back` now has 2 overloads through support or C++0x features, making the `bind` ambiguous.

```
void push_back(
   const Type&_Val
);
void push_back(
   Type&&_Val
);
```

This should work, or use the built-in function suggested in @DeadMG's answer:

```
std::vector<Device> device_list;

boost::function<void (Device&, boost::posix_time::time_duration&)> callback = 
  boost::bind(static_cast<void (std::vector<Device>::*)( const Device& )>
  (&std::vector<Device>::push_back), &device_list, _1);
```

Comment: +1. Thanks for both the explanation and the solution. I would never have thought of static-casting a function pointer ;)

Answer (score 4):

There are issues with binding in MSVC10. This isn't the first post I've seen reporting problems with it. Secondly, it's completely and totally redundant with the introduction of lambdas, and boost::function has been superseded by std::function.

```
std::vector<Device> devices;
std::function<void (Device&, boost::posix_time::time_duration&)> callback = [&](Device& dev, boost::posix_time::time_duration& time) {
    devices.push_back(dev);
};
```

There is no need to use binding in MSVC10.

Comment: btw `boost::bind` with ambiguous member function overloads is not just problematic in Visual C++, and +1 for elegant alternative

Comment: There's plenty of reason to use binding in C++0x.

Comment: @Noah: do you mean you prefer binding syntax over lambdas or are you speaking about a technical aspect (performance ?) ?

Comment: @Noah: I'll believe it when you post it. @Matthieu: From memory, lambdas are actually exceptionally fast when passing by reference- faster than you can make with function objects, because the compiler can implement them by just passing the stack pointer and offsetting from it for all variables, making the lambda smaller and more efficient.

Comment: +1. Thank you for the interesting solution. I unfortunately can't use some new C++0x features since I have to keep my code compatible with other compilers that don't provide those features.

Comment: @ereOn: If this code works in other binding compilers, you could just use conditional compilation.