# Compactify C++ function calling syntax

Tags: c++, using

I'd like to reduce amount of syntax required to refer to a function and was wondering if there was a way to do something like:

(NOT COMPILABLE)

```
using pushToLastUsed = mSomeLongStackFIFOObject.push_back;
// or
auto pushToLastUsed = mSomeLongStackFIFOObject.push_back;
```

then I could to something like:

```
pushToLastUsed(10);
```

instead of:

```
mSomeLongStackFIFOObject.push_back(10);
```

Of course I could make a macro like:

```
#define pushToLastUsed mSomeLongStackFIFOObject.push_back

// some code using it here

#undef pushToLastUsed
```

but I'd prefer not to use macros.

Comment: You could wrap it in an anonymous function. I don't know if that would cause any problems in C++, but I commonly do that in Clojure if I locally need a function many times; especially if the arguments remain the same except for one or two.

Comment: @Carcigenicate I think that is a good idea, but you add a tiny bit of overhead I would prefer to avoid, and it wouldn't be available pre C++11 (albeit the answer I am looking for is post C++11).

Comment: @MichaelChoi Many reasons, first you obfuscate your code which otherwise would be clean and self-explanatory, second you shadow away the container from the reader you are pushing to. Third, function-like macros like this are not recommended.

Comment: Of course this is just your example, but by omitting stack, FIFO and object the name would already be much shorter. You should not use the type name in the variable name (too much work if you change the type), and of course it's an object.

Comment: @Rene Yes that is definitely true. I did intentionally add certain attributes like "object" and "FIFO" just to make the name longer to make it easier to see a motivation behind my question.

Comment: @plasmacel I see. I'd definitely avoid function-like macros in the first place, but I can see how hiding the container from the reader could be a big problem.

Comment: @MichaelChoi Don't worry about overhead for using anonymous functions.  All major compilers are *exceptionally* good at inlining lambdas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you're writing `mSomeLongStackFIFOObject.push_back(10);` you're actually calling `SomeLongStackFIFOClass::push_back(&mSomeLongStackFIFOObject, 10);`

One option is to do:

```
auto& m= mSomeLongStackFIFOObject;
```

And then:

```
m.push_back(10);
```

It will shorten it and still let you use any variable you like.

If the variable is global, you can always do:

```
static inline void pushBack(int n) { mSomeLongStackFIFOObject.push_back(n); }
```

If you're trying to shorten the access, I can guess that you're using the variable more than once; then it *could* make sense to try to put all the accesses in a function that belongs to the class.

Comment: I am guessing that when you do auto& m, the reference is like a direct call then right? So m.push_back should literally compile to the same code as mSomeLongStackFIFOObject.push_back iirc?

Comment: `auto& m= mSomeLongStackFIFOObject` and then `m.push_back` is from the point of view of the language equivalent to `auto mp= &mSomeLongStackFIFOObject` and then `mp->push_back`. But I think any modern compiler would optimize that out.

Comment: I actually don’t see how this answers the question. It provides an alternative that might be of practical relevance. But from a language standpoint of view it doesn’t address the problem described in the question.

Answer (score 6):

One solution might be to use a lambda expression to capture the function call into a callable object :

```
#include <vector>

void foo(std::vector<int> & bar)
{
    auto pushToLastUsed = [&bar](int index) {
        bar.push_back(index);
    };

    pushToLastUsed(10);
}
```

Though in my opinion there is very little to gain from doing this, even if you replace `bar` with a very long identifier.

Answer (score 2):

My first idea was something along the line of the other answer. On a second read of your question I understand that it is mainly the long name of the object that you want to avoid to repeat. Hiding a call to a standard function should be done with care as its main effect is to obfuscate your code. Everybody knows what `push_back` does, but even you will likely forget what exactly `pushToLastUse` does. A different option is to alias only the `mSomeLongStackFIFOObject` with a shorter name as in

```
auto& short_name = mSomeLongStackFIFIObject;
short_name.push_back(10);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve the desired behaviour by binding the object `mSomeLongStackFIFOObject` to the member function `push_back` and using a placeholder for its argument. This requires at least a C++11 compiler.

Consider the following example:

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

struct A {
  void push_back(const int& n) { std::cout << "push_back(" << n << ")\n"; }
};

int main() {
  A mSomeLongStackFIFOObject;

  std::function<void(const int&)> pushToLastUsed = std::bind(
    &A::push_back,
    &mSomeLongStackFIFOObject,
    std::placeholders::_1
  );

  pushToLastUsed(10);  // push_back(10)
}
```

Some notes about this:

1. As Mirko already mentioned correctly, calling a non-static member function is basically the same as calling a static member function with `this` as implicit first parameter. The binding of an instance of `struct A` as first parameter makes use of this fact.
2. Type inference using `auto` does work for member functions without any parameters but not in the case above.
3. If the non-static member function is overloaded (e.g. `std::vector<T>::push_back`) you have to explicitly state the template parameters for the function template `std::bind`. See [Using std::tr1::bind with std::vector::push_back](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6007563/using-stdtr1bind-with-stdvectorpush-back)
    or [Are there boost::bind issues with VS2010?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4248357/are-there-boostbind-issues-with-vs2010) for further information.